# Is there any way to write ArrayList of <String> into csv file by using "|" as seperator?

Tags: java, string, csv, arraylist

I have bunch of ArrayList objects inside List.

I need to write all the ArrayList objects into a csv file which with pipe "|" separator.

```
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\test2.csv";
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file);

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile, '|',
                CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);



        List<ArrayList<String>> databaseColListToFetch=databaseColList;
        for(int i=0;i<databaseColList.size();i++){
            ArrayList<String> al=databaseColList.get(i);
            //Need code here which will write all the ArrayList Objects into csv file
            //writer.writeAll(al);//not sure about csv writer will write ArrayList<String> 

        }
        writer.close();
```

Comment: Sure, there is...

Comment: Please post your coding effort.

Comment: what did you tried so far? what language?

Comment: Without knowing what `CSVWriter` you use, there is no answer possible.